# Можно ли специализировать класс сразу для нескольких типов?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

К примеру:

```
template<typename T> struct MyStruct{
    //...
    void foo() { cout << "T\n";}
    //...
};

template<> struct MyStruct<float>{
    //... 
    void foo() { cout << "real numbers\n";}
    //...    
};
        
template<> struct MyStruct<double>{
    //...        
    void foo() { cout << "real numbers\n";}
    //...    
};
```

Специализации `<float>` и `<double>` ведут себя одинаково.
Можно ли избавится от копипаста и сделать одну специализацию для них двух?

Comment: Стоп-стоп-стоп! Для `float` и `double` (как в коде и как вам ответили — это просто) или для `int и `double`, как вы задали в тексте вопроса (а это совсем-совсем иное дело...)?

Comment: ну как я понял, для этого нужно в enable_if_t передать свою реализацию, которая возвращает true если шаблонными параметрами является int или double. простите только заметил вместо int хотел float указать

Comment: а как бы вы реализовали специализацию для int и double к примеру?

Comment: Через логику :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).
Например, можно сделать так:

```cpp
template<class T, class = void> 
struct MyStruct{
    void foo() { cout << "T\n";}
};

template<class T> 
struct MyStruct<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>>{
    void foo() { cout << "real numbers\n";}
};

// Еще пример
template<class T> 
struct MyStruct<T, std::void_t<decltype(T::foo())>>{
    void foo() { T::foo(); }
};
```

Ну или можно использовать концепты из C++20, что-то вроде:

```cpp
template<std::floating_point T>
struct MyStruct{
    void foo() { cout << "real numbers\n";}
};
```